# Running an aspect inside the transaction boundary of the calling method

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I am having a method annotated with spring `@Transactional`  and another custom annotation `@Counter`. `@counter` is used by many other methods from different classes.

```
@Transactional
@Counter
public int myMethod() {
....
}
```

`@Counter` is intercepted by an aspect which does some count related logic and saves to DB and is marked with `@Transactional`, hence completes in different transaction than the `myMethod()`.

when I call this `myMethod()`, first this aspect is called and after it completes then the transaction for `myMethod()` is created and then executes the business logic in `myMethod()`.

Issue here is, if any exception thrown in `myMethod()`, it rolls back all the changes. But since @Counter is in different transaction, it still is processing and doing counter related updates and does not roll back the counter related changes.

My question is: is it possible to bring the aspect of `@Counter` also within the same trancaction boundary of `myMethod()`? Is it possible to create the transaction for `myMethod()` even before the `@Counter` is called?

**Edit 1:** I have tried using `@Order` (value 5) for the around aspect and for the `myMethod()` transactional order wil be inferred from context xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" order = "1"/>
```

Still transaction gets created only after aspect completes

**Edit 2:**

```
 @Aspect
    public class CounterHandler {
        @Autowired
        private counterOperation CounterOperation;
        @Around("@annotation(com.prime.monitor.counter.aspect.Counter)")
        public Object aroundAdvice(final ProceedingJoinPoint methodInvocation) {
          //counter related operation
          return counterOperation.prepareCounter(methodInvocation);
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your aspect as well?

Comment: Have you considered using an after-returning-advice? `@AfterReturning`  would be executed when a method execution returns normally.

Comment: In normal scenario, I am not having any issue. When exception is thrown in actual method, I want to rollback the DB transaction done in the around advice as well.